# Make checkbox larger in Jquery Mobile

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

Trying to make the checkbox larger in Jquery Mobile page. Nothing I seem to do will override the default CSS in the style page for mobile 1.2.0.css - The following is my fiddle of working code, but unable to make larger. I have tried .ul-checkbox set to 40px but no change

http://jsfiddle.net/jeffbarclay/xxdrf87q/

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>

<div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="acs">
<div data-role="header">
<h2>Key Performance Indicators</h2> 
</div>

<div data-role="content">    
<ul data-role="listview" data-split-icon="gear" data-theme="c">   
 <li>
   <h1>Assess Cardiac Risk Factors</h1>                                     
     <label>                                               
     <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-2b" id="checkbox-2b" data-theme="c"/>                
     <label for="checkbox-2b">
       <label> 
         <h3>Age</h3>
       </label> 
     </label>
     </label>                                              

     <label>
     <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-2b" id="checkbox-2b" data-theme="c"/>                
     <label for="checkbox-2b">
       <label> 
         <h3>Diabetes</h3>
       </label> 
     </label>
     </label>
  </li>
</ul>     
</div>
  <div data-role="footer">
  <div data-role="navbar">
  </div>    
    <h4>John Doe</h4>
  </div>        
</div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Alex Char for the fix, to clarify my final issue here was the resolution to the multiple check boxes unsolicited: The css needed to add z-index: 2; to apply to top layer checkbox and remove id from the label elements. Cleaned up extra code by removing extra label tags not needed.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>

 <div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="acs">
 <div data-role="header">
   <h2>Key Performance Indicators</h2> 
 </div>

 <div data-role="content">    
   <ul data-role="listview" data-split-icon="gear" data-theme="c">   

   <h1>Assess Cardiac Risk Factors</h1>                                     
     <label>                                               
     <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-2b" id="checkbox-2b" data-theme="c"/>                
         <h3>Age</h3>
     </label>                                              

     <label>
     <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-2b" id="checkbox-2b" data-theme="c"/>                
         <h3>Diabetes</h3>
     </label>

    </ul>     
</div>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
#checkbox-2b {
  -ms-transform: scale(4); /* IE */
  -moz-transform: scale(4); /* FF */
  -webkit-transform: scale(4); /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-transform: scale(4); /* Opera */
  padding: 20px;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z1f4poxk/)

**References:**

[transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform)

Comment: I'm not seeing a change ? - also there is a checkbox in my fiddle that should not be there ?

Comment: What do you mean there is a checkbox it shouldn't be there? This is your html. Also according to OP _Make checkbox larger in Jquery Mobile_ and that is what this code doing.

Comment: Really can't understand what do you mean. This is your html from OP(you have duplicate's id which is wrong too). This code increase the size of checkbox.

Comment: look at the fiddle example, there are 3 checkboxes, my code only has 2

Comment: @BarclayVision Look at the html in the fiddle there are two checkboxes. Probably you refer to `span` elements as checkbox?