# CSS styling for checkbox in JQuery Mobile (extra checkbox)

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

Having trouble obtaining the correct css to create a check list in jqm. with the help of [Make checkbox larger in Jquery Mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36071453/make-checkbox-larger-in-jquery-mobile/36071526?noredirect=1#comment59789561_36071526) I was able to get a larger checkbox but the results created new checkbox in undesired location? my label elements seem to be creating extra checkbox where my html doesn't have one. see [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeffbarclay/xxdrf87q/5/) example.

outer label tag is producing a checkbox and css sizing desired to make box larger is only applied to outer label box (the one that shouldn't even be there).

HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>

<div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="acs">
<div data-role="header">
  <h2>Key Performance Indicators</h2> 
</div>

<div data-role="content">    
  <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="b">   
    <li>
      <h1>Assess Cardiac Risk Factors</h1>                                     
       <label>                                               
       <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-2b" id="checkbox-2b" data-theme="b"/>      
       <label for="checkbox-2b">
         <label> 
           <h3>Age</h3>
         </label> 
       </label>
       </label>                                              

       <label>
       <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-2b" id="checkbox-2b" data-theme="b"/>      
       <label for="checkbox-2b">
         <label> 
           <h3>Diabetes</h3>
         </label> 
       </label>
       </label>
  </li>
 </ul>     
</div>

<div data-role="footer">
<div data-role="navbar">
</div>
</div>
<div>
  <h4>My Footer</h4>
</div>        

</div>
```

CSS

```
#checkbox-2b {
-ms-transform: scale(6); /* IE */
-moz-transform: scale(6); /* FF */
-webkit-transform: scale(6); /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transform: scale(6); /* Opera */
padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/xxdrf87q/7/

Looking to the documentation the right way for doing a checkbox with it's label is this:

```
<label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-0 ">Check me
</label>
```

So I changed this part:

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-2b" id="checkbox-2b" data-theme="b"/>  Age
</label>                                              
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-2b" id="checkbox-2b" data-theme="b"/> Diabetes
</label>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, Thats exactly what I wanted to accomplish. - If I need the checkbox bigger just increase the webkit and the z- var?

Comment: Increasing the  -webkit-transform: scale value, yes. The z-index is for putting the check in the top layer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to jcarrera for the fix, to clarify my final issue here was the resolution to the multiple check boxes unsolicited: The css needed to add `z-index: 2;` to apply to top layer checkbox and remove `id` from the label elements. Cleaned up extra code by removing extra label tags not needed.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>

 <div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="acs">
 <div data-role="header">
   <h2>Key Performance Indicators</h2> 
 </div>

 <div data-role="content">    
   <ul data-role="listview" data-split-icon="gear" data-theme="c">   

   <h1>Assess Cardiac Risk Factors</h1>                                     
     <label>                                               
     <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-2b" id="checkbox-2b" data-theme="c"/>                
         <h3>Age</h3>
     </label>                                              

     <label>
     <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-2b" id="checkbox-2b" data-theme="c"/>                
         <h3>Diabetes</h3>
     </label>
    </ul>     
   </div>
  <div data-role="footer">
  <div data-role="navbar">
  </div>    
    <h4>John Doe</h4>
  </div>        
</div>
```